# Populate repeated dropdown box in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, exception, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a VB.net dropdown box which is repeated in a datagrid. Basically I have a bunch of images and the user needs to select from a dropdown listwhat colour the item is so that I can then save it in the database.

```
Dim DDLPlayColorList = New DropDownList
DDLPlayColorList = dgImages.FindControl("DDLPlayColorList")

Using oConn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("doGetAllPlayColours", oConn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        oConn.Open()
        Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            DDLPlayColorList.DataSource = dr
            DDLPlayColorList.DataTextField = "playColour"
            DDLPlayColorList.DataValueField = "playColour"
            DDLPlayColorList.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

I have tried using the findcontrol function to find the control and then bind it, but it does not make a difference. The error is

> DDLPlayColorList' is not a member of 'manager_imagecolouring'.

This is my DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgImages" runat="server" Width="300" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemStyle-Width="300" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="3px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-BackColor="#eaeaea" ItemStyle-Width="100">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="image.aspx?libid=<%#Container.DataItem("id")%>">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgCategoryThumb" CssClass="lightbox-thumb" runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" ImageUrl='<%#Container.DataItem("path")%>' AlternateText="" />
                </a>
                <asp:DropDownList id="DDLPlayColorList" runat="server" CssClass="textfield">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: First cast the control: `DDLPlayColorList = dgImages.FindControl("DDLPlayColorList") as DropDownList`

Comment: okay I have just put `DDLPlayColorList = dgImages.FindControl("DDLPlayColorList") as DropDownList` and it now says `End of statement expected.` on that line

Comment: Also you already have `DDLPlayColorList` in `dgImages` so there is no need to create another dropdownlist, use this: `Dim DDLPlayColorList = dgImages.FindControl("DDLPlayColorList") as DropDownList`. What is `manager_imagecolouring` ?

Comment: That is the name of the class that the page uses. I have changed that line, however I am still getting the `End of statement expected` error

Comment: Try `Dim DDLPlayColorList As DropDownList = CType(dgImages.FindControl("DDLPlayColorList"), DropDownList)`

Comment: thanks so far for everything. that has fixed the `end of statement expected` problem. However back to this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the line `DDLPlayColorList.DataSource = dr`.

Comment: It seems _FindControl()_ not found _DDLPlayColorList_, set a breakpoint and see is that null/nothing.

Comment: I am afraid I use Dreamweaver. I have attached a copy of my datagrid in the original post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim DDLPlayColorList As DropDownList = CType(dgImages.FindControl("DDLPlayColorList"), DropDownList)

If DDLPlayColorList IsNot Nothing Then
    Using oConn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("doGetAllPlayColours", oConn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            oConn.Open()
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                DDLPlayColorList.DataSource = dr
                DDLPlayColorList.DataTextField = "playColour"
                DDLPlayColorList.DataValueField = "playColour"
                DDLPlayColorList.DataBind()

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using    
End If
```

Set the IDs of multiple dropdowns at the time of databinding:

```
private void OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Dim DDLPlayColorList As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("DDLPlayColorList"), DropDownList)
        DDLPlayColorList.ID = "DDLPlayColorList" & e.RowIndex.ToString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh super that has stopped the errors. Now any idea why it can not find the drop down? Surely it is not causing a issue with it because the control is being repeated for each row?

Comment: afraid it is still not helping with finding the control itself